# Accessing data frame columns via names using regex

Tags: regex, r, dataframe

I have a huge data.frame [350000, 431] and I need some cleaning to do on it.
One of the cleaning operation is to turn all boolean columns `c(0,1)` to `c(FALSE, TRUE)`.
I can identify these columns by the condition that the column name contains the string "include".
So I need to do something like that:

```
data.clean[,4:272] <-  ifelse(data.clean[,4:275] == 1,"TRUE", "FALSE")
```

where instead of `4:272` (index of columns that contains "include", I want to use a more robust regex for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Mimic your data (only three columns, two columns meeting the "include" condition"):

```
data.clean <- data.frame(exclude = sample(LETTERS, 3.5e5, replace=TRUE), this.include = sample(c(0,1), 3.5e5, replace=TRUE), this.include2=sample(c(0,1), 3.5e5, replace=TRUE))

> head(data.clean)
  exclude this.include this.include2
1       W            1             1
2       Y            1             0
3       F            0             0
4       W            0             1
5       B            1             0
6       M            1             1
```

Use `names` and `grep` to identify the correct columns, and use a direct logical comparison to return the values to `TRUE` and `FALSE`:

```
data.clean[,names(data.clean)[grep("include", names(data.clean))]] <- data.clean[,names(data.clean)[grep("include", names(data.clean))]] == 1

> head(data.clean)
  exclude this.include this.include2
1       W         TRUE          TRUE
2       Y         TRUE         FALSE
3       F        FALSE         FALSE
4       W        FALSE          TRUE
5       B         TRUE         FALSE
6       M         TRUE          TRUE
```

Comment: `data.clean[, grep("include", names(data.clean))]` should be enough.